# Firebase Remote Config on Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-remote-config

i've just tried to integrate firebase custom config at Vue. I'm newbie at this and got error like this
[image]

I already add firebase sdk to my project.
This is my main.js

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const config = {
  apiKey: "######################",
    authDomain: "######################",
    databaseURL: "######################",
    projectId: "######################",
    storageBucket: "######################",
    messagingSenderId: "######################",
    appId: "######################",
    measurementId: "######################"
 };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and I want to use firebase remote config on my View

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";

  remoteConfig = firebase.remoteConfig();

  // [START enable_dev_mode]
  remoteConfig.settings = {
    minimumFetchIntervalMillis: 3600000,
  };
  // [END enable_dev_mode]
  // [START set_default_values]
  remoteConfig.defaultConfig = ({
    'is_auto_location': 'false',
  });
  // [END set_default_values]

  remoteConfig.ensureInitialized()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Firebase Remote Config is initialized');
    setLocation();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Firebase Remote Config failed to initialize', err);
  });

  function setLocation() {
    this.isAutoLocation = remoteConfig.getString('is_auto_location');
  }

</script>
```

please help.
Thankyou

Comment: import firebase in main.js file (  import * as firebase from 'firebase' )

Answer (score 1):

import firebase in main.js file `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`

there have an awesome vuejs package for firebase call [vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/). you can use it

Comment: @otniel please update your question then as it is not there